# Reading a MD25Q128SIG SPI flash memory with raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, memory, flash

I'm trying to read a **MD25Q128SIG** SPI flash memory with my raspberry pi, you can find its datasheet here: http://www.firstjit.com/Uploadfiles/20160121152131319.pdf

Here are raspberry pi pinouts:

[image]

Here are the pinouts of my chip:

[image]

and its descriptions:

[image]

I've connected like this in my raspberry pi:

FLASH / RPI

1 - 24

2 - 21

3 - ?

4 - 9 (GND)

5 - 19

6 - 23

7 - ?

8 - 1 (3.3v)

**My question is: where do I connect pins 3 and 7 of my flash memory? Pin 3 is write protection. Something should be done to prevent writing, I guess. And 7, which is hold/reset, what do I do? Are the other pins correct?
Also, how can I read my memory with this pinout using python and save it to the disk?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply read or write the contents in plain SPI  mode without invoking additional functionality, tie both /WP and /HOLD high, most easily to the flash chip's supply line.

Comment: you mean putting them to 3.3v?

Comment: If connected to a pi, then presumably that is your supply and I/O voltage for the chip, yes. And it looks like that is within range for your data sheet, though beware that some *other* parts are only rated for lower voltages.

Comment: What you mean other parts? Now i'm afraid to turn on. I bought a camera just to take its flash memory off and read it, I can't screw this. I'm afraid I write things to it so that's why I'm asking about the write protection. Where did you see that write protection is on if WP is HIGH?

Comment: No, write protection is *off* if /WP is high.  If you want to figure out how to activate it, you'll need to read the data sheet.  As for voltage, if you pulled the *correct* data sheet it is okay, but if you perhaps mixed up a few letters in the part number it could be a lower voltage part - for example, Winbond's parts with SIG in the name are low voltage.  You could perhaps carefully measure the voltage in the camera, even of the pads where the chip was...

Comment: If write protection is off if WP is high, then why did you say that I need to set it to high, in your answer?

Comment: Because I assumed you wanted full read/write access to the chip, not realizing there was already something else on there you intended to read but not modify.  Writing requires a software sequence anyway, and if you use something like flashrom it is *paranoid* about writing to the point of being fairly annoying to use for original development.

Comment: So I should wire WP to nothing and wire HOLD to high in order to just read?

Comment: /WP by itself won't write protect it, what /WP does is lock the write protection register against changes.

Comment: Minor correction: the Winbond parts I have that are low voltage are only coincidentally SIG (SO8, industrial, green), they are low voltage specifically because they are **W**SIG vs VSIG which is ~3v3.

Comment: So resuming: both WP and HOLD to 3.3v will work because mine is the 3.3v version and WP being LOW doesn't make write protection on anyways. Is it rigth?

Comment: If and only if you correctly matched the part to the data sheet you linked, yes.

Comment: one last thing: which hz frequency should I use here: https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev#settings ?

Comment: That really depends on your wiring.  Single digits of MHz should probably work, slower has no harm beyond taking longer.  Read it out multiple times and diff the files if you want to be sure.